# Can't access Object in my Soap Client PHP

Tags: php, json, soap, soap-client

I'm learning how to implement Soap Web Services for a project but I'm having a bit of an issue with it. I access the client and have a method that calls the Server to get data from the database. The data coming from the database is being returned as an Object and then encoded to JSON. When I run it i get this error

> SoapFault: Class 'Cow' not found in /home/ubuntu/workspace/V1Project/web_services/soap_client.php on line 10

But I tried requiring the class thinking it would "see" the Object was enfact there. But it still doesn't seem to work.

I have another method in the database that gets the data and just puts it into an array and encodes it into JSON and works fine.

```
Soap_Client.php

<?php 
require_once('../controller/classes/Cow.php');

$option = array('location' => 'https://name_of_direct/soap_service.php',
            'uri' => 'http://localhost');

try {
    $client = new SoapClient(null, $option);

    echo $client->getCow(40);

} catch (SoapFault $ex){
    var_dump($ex);
}

?>
```

And...

```
Soap_Service.php
<?php

require_once('../model/DBController.php');

$option = array('uri' => 'http://localhost/');

$server = new SoapServer(null, $option);

$server -> setObject(new DBController());

$server -> handle();

?>
```

Thank you for reading and any tips or help is hugely appreciated!